# WriteLine of the last loop iteration not executed like intended

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I want to write measurement data to an .csv file via a VBS Macro. I used WriteLine to only use one x-Axis value and several y-Axis values. I also calculate the mean value of all measurements.
everything is working fine except the last Line of the data (Last line in the .csv file) is not written correctly.

I have tried to increase and decrease the array length but the same problem occurred. So it seems that something happens in the last iteration.

Result File: [Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzORK.png)

I could probably add an empty last value to each array but is there a better way?

```
For i = 0 to (NP-1)
    Dim rsum : rsum = 0
    Dim tsum : tsum = 0
    
    'Build Frequency span
    FrSp(1,i) = srt + (i*stps)
    
    'Add up all reference and transmission measurements
    
    MSTString = RM(1)(i)
    MSRString = TM(1)(i)
    For h = 1 to NM
        rsum = rsum + CDbl(RM(h)(i))
        tsum = tsum + CDbl(TM(h)(i))
        
        If h < NM Then
            MSRString = MSRString & "," & RM(h+1)(i)
            MSTString = MSTString & "," & TM(h+1)(i)
        End If
    Next
    
    'Calculate mean values
    RMean(1,i) = rsum/NM
    TMean(1,i) = tsum/NM
    'write Values (comma separated) to the .csv file
    output.WriteLine(CStr(FrSp(1,i)) & "," & MSRString & "," & MSTString & "," & CStr(RMean(1,i)) & "," & CStr(TMean(1,i)))
Next

output.Close
```

Notepad File:[NotepadOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhwCR.png)

Last entrance: [LastLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w10s.png)

An advice would help me a lot, Thank You.

Comment: can you open the file with a notepad and make a picture? Do you have the same problem with other data sets? did you Stop the last entrance and what does Watch shows?

Comment: You need to make your sample code runnable, or at least provide enough declarations and values to make it compile.

Comment: If I open it in Notepad, I get the same results (so no extra commas or something).  The same problem occurs when use more y-values. I assume the problem comes with the If statement.  because when I extract the last value (last Line) it only adds an "Enter" at MSRString and MSTString.